# How to print a name of primary key which is used multiple times in other table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two tables

```
Team

Teamid
Teamname

Playingteams

Playingteamsid
Team1 fk(teamid)
Team2 fk(teamid)
Team3 fk(teamid)

Team table

Teamid teamname

1 kkkk
2 jjjj
3 llll
4 gggg
5 aaaa

Playingteam table
Ptid team1 team 2 team 3
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 5
3 1 2 4
```

And i want view as

Playingteams

```
Pt id       Team 1     Team2       Team3
1            Kkkk       Llll          Aaaa
2           Jjjj          Gggg        Aaaa
3          Kkkk        Jjjj           Gggg
```

so now if i want to print team1 team2 team3 name in a table what should i do?

I am using foreach to print playingteam table

```
Foreach($pt as $row)
{
  echo’
<td> ‘.$row->playingteamsid.’ </td>’
<td> ‘.$row->team1.’ </td>’
<td> ‘.$row->team2.’ </td>’
<td> ‘.$row->team3;’ </td>’
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use a subquery to achieve your output

Answer (score 0):

**In model**

```
$query = $this->db->select('team1','team2','team3')->from('playingteams')->limit(1)->get();
$array = $query->result();
return $array;
```

**In controller**

```
my_team = array();
my_team = array(
              'team1' => $array[0]->team1,
               'team2' => $array[0]->team2,
               'team3' => $array[0]->team3,
               );
```

You can print these values in view using json_encode().
To print table names take key from the array.

```
my_team = <?php echo json_encode($my_team); ?>
for(let x in my_team) {
  for(my_team.hasOwnProperty(x) {
   console.log(x); // here we can take team names
 }
}
```

Please note that thses table names are not taken from database. I assign these values in controller. if you want take theses vales from model you have to use for loop controller.

Comment: I want to print team1 name from team table

Comment: I didn’t understand